# Facebook OAuth Server: Failed in meteor

Tags: meteor, oauth, facebook-login

Hi I had managed to let FB log in work, but after I changed "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" setting in FB and than change it back again. Login is not working anymore. 
My server shows:

```
Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Facebook. 
{"access_token":"*******...",
"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5183894}
```

Any ideas? I heard open a new FB app may work, but it can't be like this every time. Thanks you!

Comment: I suggest you to hide your access_token key

Comment: I did... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve the problem, edit the meteorite packages file and replace it with:

```
accounts-facebook@1.1.0 
facebook-oauth@1.3.0
```

or update meteor version, works for me

Comment: omg it worked. Thank you so much, and thanks for the people finally updated the package...!