# Meteor package update broke SSR

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I was having an issue with Facebook login, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056282/facebook-oauth-server-failed-in-meteor/43060626).

Updating meteor and all the packages to the latest version fixed the Facebook login issue, but then I've found out that server-side rendering stopped working. I'm using [FlowRouter](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router-ssr).

I tried a different approach and instead of upgrading meteor and all the packages, I just upgraded accounts-facebook to version 1.0.12.

```
meteor add accounts-facebook@1.0.12
```

Meteor just doesn't upgrade account-facebook package, it does it do a bunch of other packages (probably to keep dependencies right), so after running the last command, this is what have changed:

```
accounts-base          upgraded from 1.2.12_1 to 1.2.14
accounts-facebook      upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.0.12
accounts-oauth         upgraded from 1.1.13 to 1.1.15
babel-compiler         upgraded from 6.9.1_1 to 6.13.0
babel-runtime          upgraded from 0.1.11_1 to 0.1.12
base64                 upgraded from 1.0.9 to 1.0.10
binary-heap            upgraded from 1.0.9 to 1.0.10
boilerplate-generator  upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.0.11
callback-hook          upgraded from 1.0.9 to 1.0.10
check                  upgraded from 1.2.3 to 1.2.4
ddp-rate-limiter       upgraded from 1.0.5 to 1.0.6
diff-sequence          upgraded from 1.0.6 to 1.0.7
ecmascript             upgraded from 0.5.8_1 to 0.5.9
ecmascript-runtime     upgraded from 0.3.14_1 to 0.3.15
ejson                  upgraded from 1.0.12 to 1.0.13
es5-shim               upgraded from 4.6.14_1 to 4.6.15
facebook               upgraded from 1.2.9 to 1.2.11
geojson-utils          upgraded from 1.0.9 to 1.0.10
http                   upgraded from 1.2.9_1 to 1.2.10
id-map                 upgraded from 1.0.8 to 1.0.9
localstorage           upgraded from 1.0.11 to 1.0.12
logging                upgraded from 1.1.15_1 to 1.1.16
meteor                 upgraded from 1.2.17_1 to 1.6.0
minimongo              upgraded from 1.0.17 to 1.0.18
modules                upgraded from 0.7.6_1 to 0.7.7
modules-runtime        upgraded from 0.7.6_1 to 0.7.7
mongo                  upgraded from 1.1.13 to 1.1.14
mongo-id               upgraded from 1.0.5 to 1.0.6
npm-mongo              upgraded from 2.2.11_1 to 2.2.11_2
oauth                  upgraded from 1.1.11 to 1.1.12
oauth2                 upgraded from 1.1.10 to 1.1.11
ordered-dict           upgraded from 1.0.8 to 1.0.9
promise                upgraded from 0.8.7 to 0.8.8
rate-limit             upgraded from 1.0.5 to 1.0.6
reload                 upgraded from 1.1.10 to 1.1.11
routepolicy            upgraded from 1.0.11 to 1.0.12
service-configuration  upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.0.11
tracker                upgraded from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1
underscore             upgraded from 1.0.9 to 1.0.10
url                    upgraded from 1.0.10 to 1.0.11
webapp                 upgraded from 1.3.11_1 to 1.3.12
```

Like the first approach, Facebook login issue has been fixed but lost SSR along the way.

Now, what could possibly be the best solution to keep both (Facebook login and SSR) working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how to fix:

- clone a copy of the [facebook package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/release-1.4.3/packages/facebook) folder from Meteor 1.4.1.3 (in my case) into packages/facebook folder within the app;
- apply commits [meteor/meteor@873f13d](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/873f13d743053fc080b5562dec786784bc52a610) and [meteor/meteor@2c5dda1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/2c5dda1675a9e3526e3a926d3ec2b45d0fab14c6).

Source: [[backport] Facebook API changes for 1.4.2.x accounts-facebook users. #8534](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/8534#issuecomment-290248672)